# Python can't import function

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have a problem. I have installed Rasa and all the required packages. But when I am trying to run my code it gives this error:

```
from rasa_core.channels.console import ConsoleInputChannel
ImportError: cannot import name 'ConsoleInputChannel' from 'rasa_core.channels.console' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rasa_core/channels/console.py)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/2441 - that object apparently no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code was written for an older version of Rasa than the one you are using to run it. According to the migration guide, `ConsoleInputChannel` has been removed. The documentation at https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/master/docs/core/old-core-migration-guide.rst#changes-to-input-and-output-channels says:

```
ConsoleOutputChannel and ConsoleInputChannel have been removed. Either use the run script to run your bot on the cmdline, or adapt the serve_application function to run from a python script.
```

You can try installing an old version, if you know which one it needs, or you can adapt your program to work with the current version of Rasa.